# Wso2 Docker Image error using Config-map parser

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm building a docker image using config-map parser. However I need to copy all the files from my repo including the metadata_config.properties file as the build fails if I do not pass that file when building in bitbucket. I'm updating the deployment.toml file with db configurations for cluster-coordination, however after building it does not connect to the cluster. Locally however, if I comment out the config parser line and build and run the image it works perfectly and the metadata_config file auto-generates with the different ids.

Below is the dockerfile configs that i'm using:

```
FROM wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0
COPY repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/TestCompositeExporter_1.0.0.car ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/
COPY repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
COPY repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
COPY lib/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/lib/
#[DO NOT REMOVE] Auto generated Docker commands for config-map parser
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/axis2/axis2.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/axis2/axis2_blocking_client.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/axis2/axis2_blocking_client.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/carbon.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/carbon.properties
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/carbon.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/carbon.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/deployment.toml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/deployment.toml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/etc/jmx.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/etc/jmx.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/internal-apis.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/internal-apis.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/jndi.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/jndi.properties
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/passthru-http.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/passthru-http.properties
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/security/cipher-text.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/security/cipher-text.properties
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/synapse-handlers.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/synapse-handlers.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/synapse.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/synapse.properties
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/user-mgt.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/user-mgt.xml
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/log4j2.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/log4j2.properties
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 wso2/components/extensions/*.jar ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/wso2/components/extensions/
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/main.xml ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/
RUN mkdir ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/resources/conf/.metadata
#The metadata_config line that I comment out for clustering to happen
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 repository/resources/conf/.metadata/metadata_config.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/resources/conf/.metadata
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 repository/resources/conf/.metadata/references.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/resources/conf/.metadata
#COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 conf/dev.properties ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/conf/dev.properties
COPY  --chown=wso2carbon:wso2 bin/micro-integrator.sh ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/bin/micro-integrator.sh
#[DO NOT REMOVE] End of auto generated Docker commands for config-map parser
```

Metadata_config.properties file looks like this:

```
    #Mon Jun 19 00:22:48 IST 2023
conf\\datasources\\master-datasources.xml=d36fb3e31f19c570d8782026d3590514
conf\\wso2-log-masking.properties=5112d6ac3870020c023a5007a413793b
conf\\axis2\\axis2_blocking_client.xml=082871facdcfbe8e8a4086df2ac6ec95
conf\\axis2\\axis2.xml=8f3faee613d3bdcaf7b06b26186cd48b
conf\\synapse-handlers.xml=3374fb177f8affe3a7165e1807749bc0
conf\\synapse.properties=1fc18394ba1c41b22d298a093e148412
conf\\security\\cipher-text.properties=bb8630dc24f1c8f3db43dfb36f081e24
conf\\etc\\jmx.xml=8b8f31f74326bcaf6287fb7bf974a32b
conf\\passthru-http.properties=f620c146d98f776b0fe6f6896e5b19aa
conf\\jndi.properties=613f9b52d735f8860d667b63c745b57e
conf\\deployment.toml=ff94196239772217110e98f9d172477a
conf\\carbon.xml=6b6fb5512d41873438097103bb0108b4
conf\\carbon.properties=4803967724d40e537f1ca3c99303473e
conf\\user-mgt.xml=b5cc1bd3c4da75b59226512676705d7a
conf\\internal-apis.xml=9c350bb70dc2811ed31a3339388afaf9
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you copying all the XML config files? Those are not needed. Just copy the `deployment.toml`, `*.car` files and any external dependencies like DB drivers.

Comment: Actually these were generated by our docker exporter project, and we've tried excluding the metadata_config file but it throws an error when building using bitbucket. Locally it works...

Comment: So far, I can get it to work by running the server locally, and then adding that updated metadata_config.properties file when building the image; then too it works. But I need to know if there's a proper way to do it.

Comment: @ahinsa As instructed please remove the unnecessary stuff and try. I have no idea what this `metadata_config.properties` is, it should be something you have added not WSO2.

Comment: No i'm not adding it, it's actually generated by wso2 mi at that path, and it contains some ids pertaining to deployment.toml, master-datasources.xml etc.  As i've mentioned before, we have no idea why it works when deploying locally but doesn't connect to the cluster when we deploy in aws using Bitbucket.

Comment: Add the content in the `metadata_config.properties` file. Just saying it doesn't work will not help me to give any solution.

Comment: Sure, sorry! I've added it in the main question